# Is there a way to set default Groovy and Grails versions in GVM?

Tags: grails, groovy, gvm

It appears that I have to type `gvm use grails x.y.z` and `gvm use groovy x.y.z` every time I reboot my PC. Is there a way to configure GVM to do set the versions on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, say `gvm default grails 2.4.4` for example

From the usage/help on command line:

```
default   or d    <candidate> [version]
```

Comment: By answering Y or simply hitting enter after using gvm to install grails x.y.z, it automatically makes x.y.z the default. Possibly you opted 'no' on first installation so that gvm had no default set.

Comment: @MarcoVermeulen No. I did the installations manually because I had downloaded them before starting to use GVM.